# Python 2.7: strange constructor behavior: changing wrong field

Tags: python, python-2.7

In this code:

```
# coding=utf-8


def print_tree(node, tree=0):
    print(u"|---" * tree + u"-> %s" % node)
    for kid in node.children:
        print_tree(kid, tree + 1)


class Person(object):
    parent = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    children = []

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, parent=None):
        if parent is not None:
            if not isinstance(parent, Person):
                raise AttributeError('`parent` is not `Person` type!')
            self.parent = parent
            self.parent.children.append(self)
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        #self.children = []


root = Person('Alan', 'Smith')
p1 = Person('Barbara', 'Smith', root)
p2 = Person('Basia', 'Smith', root)
p3 = Person('Bary', 'Smith', root)

print_tree(root)
```

If I remove comment from `#self.children = []` example works fine. But I don't understand why I must add this line ?

In debugger I discovered that the line `self.parent.children.append(self)` adds `self` also into `self.children`

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, when you declare an attribute at the class level, that makes it a class attribute (shared between all the instances of the class). In your case, you want instance attributes. Instance attributes must be created in the constructor (your `self.children = []`).

Comment: Lol, 3 years of self learning Python, bilion lines of code and You destroyed my basics :D

Comment: Sorry ;) This is not necessarly obvious if you have used other languages, but then it makes sense (class attributes at the class definition level).

Answer (score 2):

`children` is a class attribute, you want it to be an instance attribute.  You should remove `children=[]` from the class scope entirely and leave only the one in the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 0):

You've got problems because in your code `children` is a `class variable` (it is referred when you get access to it on class level, not on instance level), not an `instance variable` (which is unique for each instance).

So you must add something like:

```
self.children = []
```

each time you `__init__` your instance of `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing children from an object instance, thus you cannot keep it only in the Class scope/layer.  Thus you need `self.children = []` because otherwise you are not referring to an instance's children but the class'.  (And the syntax for the latter would be `Person.children`)

Comment: (2) is not correct.  He's adding `self` to the `child` list of the parent, which is perfectly valid, if not perfectly intuitive to read.

Comment: My mistake.  I will remove that portion of the answer.  Thank you for the catch!  (That's my problem: Trying to be fast with my answer and missing an important detail!)